# How to detect if child is clicked on parent click React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React and I have the following situation.

I have one parent div with `onClick` event, which takes full width and inside that div I have an image. I want to be able to know where it is clicked. Thus, I want to know if image (child) or div(parent) is clicked.

My code is as follows:

```
class APP extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)   
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="parent" onClick={(e) => console.log("PARENT CLICK")}>
        <img src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg"
          style={{maxWidth: "60%", maxHeight: "90%", pointerEvents: 'none', zIndex: 99999}}
          onClick={e => console.log("IMAGE CLICK")}
          />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<APP />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

But it detects always the parent click. I tried to add `z-index` to the child, but I think that child can't be in front of parent.

[Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/apmoj08r/2/)

Comment: you don't need `e.stopPropagation` for your use-case. See my updated answer.

Comment: yes, there are again many ways to achieve the requirement but he has two `onclick` functions in his code, that's why `e.stopPropagation` is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class APP extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props)   
}

handleclick(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
 console.log(e.target.tagName);
 return false;
}   
render() {
  return (
    <div className="parent" onClick={(e) => this.handleclick(e)}>
    <img src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg"
      style={{maxWidth: "30%", maxHeight: "30%", zIndex: 99999}}
      onClick={(e) => this.handleclick(e)}
      />
  </div>
 )
}
} 

ReactDOM.render(<APP />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

please note here I added `e.stopPropagation()` in the click event which only executes with the target element.. here you can read more about [propogation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

and also please remove the CSS `pointerEvents: 'none'` from the `img` tag, it works fine.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/designerPrasanna/o30sgpre/)

Answer (score 1):

You have `pointerEvents` set to `none` in your `img`'s inline `style` object. Remove that. Can remove `zIndex` as well.

From [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/):-

> `pointer-events:none` prevents all click, state and cursor options on
> the specified HTML element

You don't need `e.stopPropagation()` here. Just set the event handler only on **parent** like so (this is known as **event delegation**) :-

```
class APP extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)   
  }
  
  handleclick(e){
    console.log(e.target.tagName);
  }  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="parent" onClick={this.handleclick}>
        <img src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg"
          style={{maxWidth: "30%", maxHeight: "30%"}}
          />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<APP />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Answer (score 1):

pointerEvents : none will block the pointer events.Remove that from your styling

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is the react way of doing this but in javascript you can use the event object properties to get the element that triggered it with `event.target` and the element that handled it with `event.currentTarget`.

```js
document.querySelector('#parent').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(`clicked element is: ${e.target.id}`);
  console.log(`event handler element is: ${e.currentTarget.id}`);
});
```

```html
<div id='parent'>parent
  <div id='child'>child</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As [CodeBug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12916691/codebug) noted above it should be enough to **stop the propagation** on the click event by calling (inside of the onClick function):

```
event.stopPropagation();
```